# Partition manager that can handle LVM?

Tags: partition, lvm

I have been looking but neither Gparted nor KDE Partition Manager can handle LVM. Working with the command line is probably fine but it would be clearer to have a GUI tool here. Does such thing exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RedHat's set of administration tools, there's [system-config-lvm](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-system-config-lvm.html), which is optionally installable in other distributions like Fedora and Debian.

Recent versions of [gnome-disk-utility](http://library.gnome.org/users/palimpsest/) support LVM.

The newly-released [KDE 4.6](http://www.kde.org/announcements/4.6/) gains [udisks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks) as a [Solid](http://solid.kde.org/) backend, which should provide LVM support.  (Out of the three, this is the only one I haven't tried.)

Comment: gnome-disk-utility lets me see the existing logical volumes but not create or edit them. Is that what you mean by support, or is my version too low (2.30.1)?

Comment: And I don't understand your point about udisks and solid... The links point to something strange. How do I install and try them?

Comment: Accepting this answer because system-config-lvm works quite well on Ubuntu. I have problem installing it in Gentoo though.

Comment: In even newer news, system-config-lvm has apparently been replaced by gnome-disk-utility, which has been renamed to palimpsest (and has an 11-word manual!), which was apparently eviscerated to produce gnome-disks, which if available has very limited functionality. Or, put differently, Josh McGee below is correct that you should use the 'lvm' command because now that's all you have available to use.

Comment: Minusing because though it was probably an accurate answer 3 years ago, it's not anymore, per fencepost's comment — system-config-lvm is not maintained anymore and not available in latests Fedora versions, and gnome-disks *does lack* LVM support, if by "support" we mean ability to modify the setup.

Answer (score 5):

In KDE there is 'kvpm' available.

I use it to handle all LVM related issue when I have a GUI available.

```
sudo apt-get install kvpm
```

Comment: Works best. Supports setting up the volume and extending live.

Comment: it runs even on ubuntu 20.04, just install the 18.04 packages https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608708/30352

Comment: @Aquarius Power: that's the last release in which it will work [probably](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/kvpm/#comment-803628), because lvm2app got deprecated

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck I expect new tools can handle stripes as the only one available at that time (I dont know today) did not have such feature. If it cant handle, I will just not upgrade ubuntu :/ as I need that feature for performance, good it is LTS :).

Comment: I've tested blivet it is mostly fine.

Answer (score 3):

What you really want to use is the lvm2 command-line tool `lvm` to ensure *complete* control over how things are setup and managed.

I know, how snarky and elitist of me. The minimal set of commands you should learn are `{pv,vg,lv}create` and their `^create^re{move,size}` counterparts. Particularly with the `-r|--resize` flag for resizing.

This is *very* simple to figure out, and you will thank yourself graciously for not falling on the GUI utilities that are highly limited in functionality. I promise.

Comment: I like the command line as much as the next guy, but I struggle to understand why a GUI could not give you complete control over something like this.

Comment: And with visualized partitions, it's much less error-prone to use a GUI, because it's harder to type the wrong things. That's why even though I can do whatever GParted does using `fdisk` some `mkfs`, I still use GParted whenever I can.

Answer (score 2):

KDE Partition Manager 3.0 can handle LVM including encrypted LVM case.

Answer (score 1):

LVM volumes on CentOS / RHEL 7 are now managed with System Storage Manager. The system-config-lvm tool has been deprecated.

```
yum install system-storage-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

[alterator](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/alterator)'s [alterator-vm](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/alterator-vm) module is a partition manager that works with LVM, too.

It is used as the default tool in ALT's distros, also in the installer. I'm not sure whether it's easy to install it in a distro other than ALTLinux.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSuSE has long had LVM support in the YaST Partitioner
http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.advdisk.html#sec.yast2.system.lvm.yast

Answer (score 0):

`blivet-gui` is what you want. Still not as flexible as the CLI, sadly.

Comment: But doesn't it have very limitted resize capability? E.g. what if I have btrfs as LVM logical volume?

Comment: Generally speaking there is little point to put `btrfs` on logical volumes. I would be glad to know of one use case when it might help