# Reduce LVM /tmp size to 10G and add everything to / root dir

Tags: partition, lvm

I want to reduce the partition mounted at `/tmp` to 10GB and add all unused space to the `/` partition.

If I `umount -l /tmp` and run `fsck.ext3 -f /dev/privg/lv_tmp`, I get this:

```
fsck.ext3: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/privg/lv_tmp
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?
```

What are the correct steps to do LVM repartitioning?

```
$ df -hl
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/privg-lv_root   12G  4.2G  6.9G  38% /
/dev/mapper/privg-lv_tmp    29G  3.2G   24G  12% /tmp
/dev/mapper/privg-lv_var   3.9G  1.5G  2.3G  40% /var
/dev/sda1                  494M   40M  429M   9% /boot
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Have you seen/tried [this?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/partition-manager-that-can-handle-lvm)

Comment: There's no win manager/admin tools installed.  It's running on run level 3.  OS is RHEL5.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unmount the ext3 filesystem in order to shrink it. `umount -l` means that the filesystem will be unmounted when there is no more open file on it.

Run `lsof /tmp` to see what files are open on `/tmp`. If you're running an X server, you'll see its socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`. You can't remove that socket¹ and still be able to connect to the X server. Other than that, most files tend to be short-lived or to belong to programs that can be restarted.

If you really want to perform the operation on a live system, you'll need to migrate to a different `/tmp` filesystem, at least for the duration of the operation. You could transition to tmpfs, in which `/tmp` is stored in RAM or swap; see [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/175861/ramdisk-ubuntu-10-04/175882#175882). In fact, tmpfs for `/tmp` is a common setup; you might want to stick to that and remove the `/tmp` partition altogether (and perhaps enlarge your swap a little instead).

Once you've been able to close everything from `/tmp`, you'll be able to unmount it. Don't use `umount -l`, it's useless here since it frees the mount point but not the device, whereas what you want is to free the device. Once `/tmp` is unmounted, run `fsck`, run `resize2fs` to shrink it, and shrink the LVM logical volume accordingly. Or you might in fact save time by directly shrinking the LVM volume and creating a new filesystem for `/tmp`. (If you have any data you want to keep in `/tmp`, you're doing it wrong. `/tmp` is for data that need not be saved between reboots, and closed files in `/tmp` are fair game for deletion.)

If all this seems daunting, reboot to a recovery system (live CD or USB) and operate from there.

¹  <sub>Nor can you move it to another filesystem: that would be removing the original and creating a new socket.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can't unmount /tmp on a running system.  You need to boot from a LiveCD or rescue CD and do it there.