# How to get a dual boot (2 Linux OSs) system working when both are LUKS-encrypted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot, luks

I followed [my own instructions here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728750/114401) to shrink down a LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu 20.04 partition and its inner LVM volume so I could install Ubuntu 22.04 in a new LUKS-encrypted partition next to it, but after installing the LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu 22.04 OS, the LUKS-encrypted 20.04 installation (in a separate encrypted partition) is no longer in the Grub boot menu. Why? How do I get this dual boot to work properly? Should I have put *both* OS's in the *same* LUKS-encrypted partition, just in different LVM volumes within that partition?

Here's my disk, as shown in gparted while logged into the new Ubuntu 22.04 OS.

Description:

1. `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is the 512 MiB EFI partition
2. `/dev/nvme0n1p2` is the ext4 /boot non-encrypted partition for the old Ubuntu 20.04 OS
3. `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is the LUKS-encrypted partition containing a single LVM volume with Ubuntu 20.04 in it (no longer in the grub menu)
4. `/dev/nvme0n1p4` is the ext4 /boot non-encrypted partition for the new Ubuntu 22.04 OS
5. `/dev/nvme0n1p5` is the LUKS-encrypted partition containing a single LVM volume with Ubuntu 22.04 in it (*is* in the grub menu, and is the OS running right now)

[image]

These look potentially useful:

1. [Ask Ubuntu: How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/293028/327339)
2. [Ask Ubuntu: how do I boot into a LUKS-encrypted environment?](https://askubuntu.com/a/166030/327339) - helps me clearly see the definitions of LUKS-partition vs LVM vs logical volumes within it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

##### How to add other LUKS-encrypted Linux distributions back to your Grub bootloader startup menu: quick summary

```bash
# 1. Open your `/etc/default/grub` file.
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
# Then manually add these lines to the bottom of that file:
# (required)
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
# (optional)
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# 2. Unlock your LUKS-encrypted partitions which contain other bootable
# operating systems. In my case:
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt

# 3. Update your Grub bootloader in your `/boot` partition. 
sudo update-grub
# When I run `update-grub`, my output now includes this line:
#
#       Found Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (20.04) on /dev/mapper/system-root

# 4. Done. Reboot to see and use the new Grub entries!
reboot
```

For a *ton* more details and information, see my much longer answer here: [Ask Ubuntu: How to get old LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu version back into Grub menu after installing new Ubuntu version in new LUKS partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1457957/327339)